# how to reset a "readonly=true" input field in a form created from php to "readonly=false" using javascript/jquery?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, arrays

I have a form created from a php file, and a text field, which has a readonly attr, on clicking edit button(the edit button is also created during the input field is created), I want the said field to be editable, how can i do that?

```
<td text align="center">
<input type="text" id=SOME_AMOUNT<?= $j; ?> value=<?=" " .$arr[$j]['BILL_AMOUNT'] . "  "; ?> readOnly>
<button type="button" id=EDIT_AMOUNT<?php echo "$j"; ?> class="EDIT_AMOUNT btn btn-mini btn-primary"> Edit Bill</button>

$(document).ready(funcion(){
    $(".EDIT_AMOUNT").click(function(){
        var id=$(this).attr('id');
        var index=id.match(/\d+$/)[0]; // to get the id numerals from the id string
        $("#SOME_AMOUNT"+index).attr("readOnly", false);
    }); 
});
```

Edit: the problem seems to lie in the javascript used for table alignment which is included in the php file.. how is that possible?

Answer (score 2):

Try this (pure JS):

```
document.getElementById('SOME_AMOUNT').readonly = false;
```

Comment: @L4reds: Of course you have to use the actual id, yours seem to have a suffix.

Comment: i know that.. still it's not working, what might be wrong with it?

Comment: @L4reds: Does the button submit the form?

Comment: nope.. it's just to serve that very purpose. i just found out that another javascript source file i'm using seems to prevent this happening..i'm not so sure..

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$("#SOME_AMOUNT"+index).attr('readOnly', false);
```

or

```
 $("#SOME_AMOUNT"+index).removeAttr('readOnly');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this for jquery:

```
$('element').attr('some attribute','some attributes value')
```

Inn your case it would be:

```
$('you_elemnt').attr("readOnly", false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the attribute;

```
 $("#SOME_AMOUNT"+index).removeAttr('readonly');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $('#FullName').attr('readOnly', false);
```

Or try this

```
 $('#FullName').removeAttr('readonly');
```